# What is the expression for getting a subset of characters in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a column of 10 character names e.g. L3NAM1988K. How can I delete the first 5 characters and the last 1 character using an expression in the QGis Field Calculator?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `substr` function under `String` list for example: `substr( 'L3NAM1988K', 6, 4 )`

[image]